how i will dump ssh session data to a file in teststand 2017 using plink
Can some body shared the detailed procedures to dump ssh terminal logs into a file using plink utility. Command line based approach is required.
New to TestStand Environment, i have not any clue how to proceed.I have tried execute binary steps by providing the required path to plink executable.
